# PHP in bootstrap form not working

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to add php to a bootstrap form via the following tutorial: https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/working-bootstrap-contact-form/. But nothing happens when I click the submit button - I just go back/stay to the same page with an empty form. I don't receive an email nor any error actions when I don't fill out some fields either. Below my code. The name of the document is *werkwijze.php*. Does someone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks a lot in advance!

```
<?php
              if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
                  $voornaam = $_POST['voornaam'];
                  $familienaam = $_POST['familienaam'];
                  $email = $_POST['email'];
                  $tel = $_POST['tel'];
                  $vraag = $_POST['vraag'];
                  $from = 'info@tbep.be'; 
                  $to = 'eefje.vanhemelryck@gmail.com'; 
                  $subject = 'Vraag van op uw website www.tbep.be';

                  $body = "From: $voornaam $familienaam\n E-Mail: $email\n Telefoon: $tel\n Vraag: $vraag";

                  // Check if name has been entered
                  if (!$_POST['voornaam']) {
                      $errVoornaam = 'Gelieve uw voornaam op te geven';
                  }

                  if (!$_POST['familienaam']) {
                      $errFamilienaam = 'Gelieve uw familienaam op te geven';
                  }

                  // Check if email en phone has been entered and is valid
                  if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                      $errEmail = 'Gelieve uw emailadres op te geven';
                  }

                  if (!$_POST['tel']) {
                      $errTel = 'Gelieve uw telefoonnummer op te geven';
                  }

                  //Check if message has been entered
                  if (!$_POST['vraag']) {
                      $errVraag = 'Gelieve uw vraag te stellen';
                  }


          // If there are no errors, send the email
          if (!$errVoornaam && !$errFamilienaam && !$errEmail && !$errTel && !$errVraag) {
              if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
                  $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Hartelijk dank. Ik neem zo snel mogelijk contact met u op!</div>';
              } else {
                  $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry, er was een probleem met het versturen van dit formulier. Alternatief kan u ons een email sturen op info@tbep.be</div>';
              }
          }
              }
          ?> 

        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="werkwijze.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="voornaam">Voornaam:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="voornaam" name="voornaam" placeholder="Voornaam">
                <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errVoornaam</p>";?>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="familienaam">Familienaam:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="familienaam" name="familienaam" placeholder="Familienaam">
                <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errFamilienaam</p>";?>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="email">Email:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="telefoon">Telefoonnummer:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Telefoonnummer">
                <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errTel</p>";?>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="vraag">Uw vraag:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="vraag" name="vraag" placeholder="Uw vraag"></textarea>
                <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errVraag</p>";?>
              </div>
            </div>               
            <div class="form-group">        
              <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default">Versturen</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
                  <?php echo $result; ?>    
              </div>
          </div>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Remove enctype="text/plain" from your form.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="werkwijze.php" method="post">
```

Or use

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="werkwijze.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```